# How can I change to a default background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following function to create dynamic elements using an ajax response.

```
function itemGroupSelection(elem,majorGroupId,itemGroupId){

    var itemGroup;
    var majorGroup;

    if(elem == undefined || elem == null || elem == ""){
        var itemGroup = itemGroupId;
        var majorGroup = majorGroupId;
    }else if(majorGroupId == null && itemGroupId == null){
        var itemGroup = elem.attr("id");
        var majorGroup = elem.attr("majorgroup");
    }



    $('.breadcrumb a').removeClass('active');

    if(elem == ""){
        $('.breadcrumb a').first().addClass('active');
    }else{
        elem.addClass('active');
    }

    var selectedOutlet = $('#outlets select').children(":selected").attr("id");
    $('.item').show();
    $('.breadcrumb').show('1');
    var data = "majorGroupId=" + majorGroup + "&itemGroupId=" + itemGroup + "&outletCode=" + selectedOutlet;

    if(selectedOutlet == undefined){
        getSystemMessage('Please select an outlet.');
    }else{
        ajaxCall("/getItems","POST",data,function(result){
            var element = $('#model-item').find('.item').first();
            $('#item-list-section').empty();

            for(var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++){
                var clone = element.clone();

                clone.attr("id", result.items[i].itemId);
                clone.find('.item-price').html("<h4>" + result.items[i].rate.toFixed(2) + "</h4>");
                if(result.items[i].itemName.length >= 20){
                    clone.find('.item-name').css('overflow','hidden');
                    clone.attr('title', result.items[i].itemName )
                }
                clone.find('.item-name').html("<h4>"+ result.items[i].itemName + "</h4>");
                clone.css('background-image','c:/zharaimages/' + result.items[i].itemId + '/image.jpg');

                clone.draggable({
                    revert : false,
                    zIndex: 1,
                    containment: "window",
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    cursor: "move",
                    helper: function() { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show(); }
                });
                $('#item-list-section').append(clone);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Using the following command I try to select the background image in the local disc.

```
clone.css('background-image','c:/zharaimages/' + result.items[i].itemId + '/image.jpg');
```

How can i switch to a default image if there is no image in the path defined. I'm using jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Why do you use files from local disk? How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `onerror` event of this image, which will occur whenever the file cannot be found:

```
$('#image').error(function(){
    $(this).off('error'); // otherwise, inexistence of the default image is a real pain
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
});
```

Take a look at this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M6M8T/1/).

---

Then,

in your situation, you could have something like this:

```
var path='the path';

clone.css('background-image', 'url('+path+')');
$('<img src="'+path+'" />').error(function(){
    $(this).off('error');
    clone.css('background-image', 'url('+default_path+')');
});
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onerror attribute of img, if the link given in src attribute fails to load, ur function in error is called and u can set your default image there (w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp)